What wildcards will work with Make's .INTERMEDIATE target?
Isn't there some wildcard I can use for Make's .INTERMEDIATE target?
$ cat Makefile
.INTERMEDIATE: *.csv %.csv #failed
.INTERMEDIATE: north.csv g.csv #worked

Or must I list each and every file each and every time? Does any brand of Make allow wildcards here? The various manuals are not clear.
The line above marked "worked" worked, as the matching files got removed.

The way I've done this sort of thing (with regular targets, but I don't see why this won't work here) is to set a variable using the wildcard command, and use that in the dependencies.
e.g.
SRC = $(wildcard *.go)

bootstrap: $(SRC)
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -trimpath -o bootstrap $(SRC)
        strip bootstrap

So I would try something like:
CSV=$(wildcard *.csv)

.INTERMEDIATE: $(CSV)


I have some bad news for you. It seems at the time when the wildcard command is run, the .csv's don't exist yet. Thus this solution fails. Else I could also just use .INTERMEDIATE: $(wildcard *.csv) too.
